# am I covered by retirement plan at work (for TIRA contribution deductibility)?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, ira

I retired early in 2021.   I am trying to determine if I am considered "covered by a retirement plan at work" for purposes of the MAGI limits for deductibility of a TIRA contribution for 2021.

In "similar questions" it appears that if I was covered by a retirement plan at ANY time during 2021, then the answer is "yes", I am "covered by a retirement plan at work".  However, on my W-2, the "retirement plan" box is NOT checked (in box 13).

Even though I was eligible for a retirement plan during the month or so I worked during 2021, I had nothing deducted from my gross pay (for reasons I do not recall), that is, there are no entries in box 12 (and my "wages" are the same as my "social security wages).

Am I correct, that for purposes of the MAGI limits on TIRA contribution deductibility, that I am "not covered by a retirement plan at work" ?

Comment: What kind of retirement plan was it?

Comment: Defined contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as no employer-based retirement plan contributions were made by you or on your behalf (i.e. non-elective contributions), you would be considered **not** covered by a retirement plan in 2021. But ultimately it comes down to what's checked in box 13 of your W-2, and since it's not, you should definitely be fine. More details from the IRS [here](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/are-you-covered-by-an-employers-retirement-plan).